# recreating interactive workspace in react. How to migrate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-transforms, dom-manipulation

So I originally created a program that allows an interactive workspace that allows users to drag around the page and move everything inside the container with it using pure JavaScript. code is as follows.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L05zorc7/2/

So as you can see in the example if you drag the blank space you can move the child in it.

But I want to migrate this program into a react component. I tried just doing this but it does not work.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef  } from 'react';
import './workspace.css'

const Workspace = () => {
  const workspaceRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const workspaceContainerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);


  // while the conf change, modify workspace accordingly
  const workspaceConf = new Proxy({ movementX: 0, movementY: 0, scale: 1 }, {
    set: (target, key, value) => {
      target[key as keyof typeof target]  = value;
      if (["movementX", "movementY"].includes(key as string) ) { // i.e., if movement changed
        if(workspaceRef.current){
          workspaceRef.current.style["translate"] = `${target.movementX}px ${target.movementY}px`;
        }
      }

      return true; // set handler should return true if success.
    }
  });

  // init workspace
  Object.keys(workspaceConf).forEach((key) => {
    workspaceConf[key as keyof typeof workspaceConf] = workspaceConf[key as keyof typeof workspaceConf];
  });

  // move the workspace while mouse dragging
  if(workspaceContainerRef.current){
    workspaceContainerRef.current.addEventListener("mousedown", e => {
    if (e.target !== workspaceContainerRef.current) return;
    // prevent unexpected workspace movement (e.g. while blocks being dragged)

    const move = (e:any) => { // mousemove event
      workspaceConf.movementX += e.movementX;
      workspaceConf.movementY += e.movementY;
    }

    document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", move);
    document.body.addEventListener(
      "mouseup",
      e => document.body.removeEventListener("mousemove", move), { once: true }
    );
    });}

  

  return (
    <div
    id="workspaceContainer"
      ref={workspaceContainerRef}
      style={{ width: "100vw", height: "100vh", margin: 0, padding: 0, overflow: "hidden" }}
    >
      <main
        id="workspace"
        ref={workspaceRef}
      >
        <div className="block">
          <div className="header">Sample</div>
          <div className="content">Yes</div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Workspace;
```

And in the main App root component:

```
import React from 'react';
import WorkspaceComponent from './components/workspace';
//import Menu from './components/menu';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <WorkspaceComponent/>
    </>
    
  );
}
export default App;
```

It doesn't seem like it is working can anyone help?

Can anyone give me a few lessons on how components work differently from pure js when it comes to dom manipulation?

I have tried using useState to track movement and useEffect ot modify css translate while movement state alters, but failed. So I resort to using an almost exact code from my original pure css code.

my approach using useState and useEffect Hooks

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef  } from 'react';
import './workspace.css'

const Workspace = () => {

  const workspaceRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const workspaceContainerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  
  const [workspaceConfState, setWorkspaceConfState] = useState({
    movementX: 0,
    movementY: 0,
  });


  useEffect(() =>{
    if(workspaceRef.current !== null ){
      workspaceRef.current.style["translate"] = `${workspaceConfState.movementX}px ${workspaceConfState.movementY}px`;
    } 
  },[workspaceConfState])

  if(workspaceContainerRef.current){
    workspaceContainerRef.current.addEventListener("mousedown", (e: any) =>{
      if(e.target !== workspaceContainerRef.current) return;
      
      const move = (event:any) => {
        setWorkspaceConfState((prevConf) => ({
          ...prevConf,
          movementX: prevConf.movementX + event.movementX,
          movementY: prevConf.movementY + event.movementY,
        }));
      };
  
      document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', move);
      document.body.addEventListener(
        "mouseup",
        e => document.body.removeEventListener("mousemove", move), { once: true }
      );
      
    })
  }
  return (
    <div
    id="workspaceContainer"
      ref={workspaceContainerRef}
      style={{ width: "100vw", height: "100vh", margin: 0, padding: 0, overflow: "hidden" }}
    >
      <main
        id="workspace"
        ref={workspaceRef}
      >
        <div className="block">
          <div className="header">Sample</div>
          <div className="content">Yes</div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Workspace;
```

Answer (score 0):

So after a few trials and errors. It turned out that altering transform through `.style` with code is not a good idea, instead pass the style state into `style` variables in the render function is the answer

```
import React, { useState, MouseEvent } from 'react';
import './workspace.css'

interface WorkspaceConf {
    movementX: number;
    movementY: number;
}

const Workspace: React.FC = () => {
    const [workspaceConf, setWorkspaceConf] = useState<WorkspaceConf>({
        movementX: 0,
        movementY: 0
    });

    const handleMouseDown = (e: any) => {
        if (e.target !== document.getElementById('workspaceContainer')) return;

        const move = (moveEvent: any) => {
            setWorkspaceConf(workspaceConf => ({
                movementX: workspaceConf.movementX + moveEvent.movementX,
                movementY: workspaceConf.movementY + moveEvent.movementY
            }));
        };

        const handleMouseUp = () => {
            document.body.removeEventListener('mousemove', move);
        };

        document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', move);
        document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp, { once: true });
    };

    return (
        <div id="workspaceContainer" onMouseDown={handleMouseDown} style={{height: '100vh'}}>
            <main
                id="workspace"
                style={{ transform: `translate(${workspaceConf.movementX}px, ${workspaceConf.movementY}px)` }}>

                <div className="block">
                    <div className="header">Sample</div>
                    <div className="content">Yes</div>
                </div>

            </main>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Workspace;
```